# arguments to Cmd not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

From my previous question here I was writing a program that executes A number of files through CMD.

Here is my Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Convert
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
        Open.Filter = "RIFF/RIFX (*.Wav)|*.wav";
        Open.CheckFileExists = true;
        Open.Multiselect = true;
        Open.ShowDialog();
        LstFile.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string file in Open.FileNames)
        {
            LstFile.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LstFile.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {       Process p = new Process();      
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            foreach (string fn in LstFile.Items)
            {
                string fil = "\"";
                string gn = fil + fn + fil;
                p.Start();
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = gn;
            }            
        }      
    }    
}
```

i used

```
string fil = "\"";
string gn = fil + fn + fil;
```

to provide quotation marks around the full file name in case the filename has spaces.

My problem is that my program Opens CMD Put does not pass any arguments in it.I checked if the filnames(list) are working and they are fine.Looking at the examples this is the way to do it,but obviously something is wrong

Comment: Setting `StartInfo.Arguments` after you call `Start()` looks wrong

Comment: AFAIK those were there by default.I just added system.diagnostics

Comment: @default.kramer Changing the position didn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

```
StartInfo.Arguements
```

Before you start the process, and I'd suggest making a new process class for each process that you start.

example:

```
foreach (string fn in LstFile.Items)
{
    string fil = "\"";
    string gn = fil + fn + fil;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = gn;
    //You can do other stuff with p.StartInfo such as redirecting the output
    p.Start();
    // i'd suggest adding p to a list or calling p.WaitForExit();, 
    //depending on your needs.  
}
```

If you're trying to call cmd commands, make your arguements

`"/c \"what i would type into the command Line\""`

This is an example of what I did quick.  It opens a text document in notepad

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"New Text Document.txt\"";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I tried it,but the result is the same.Just cmd,no sign of my filename or anything else

Comment: @Cesar What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Cesar i added another part at the end.  maybe you could try that.

Comment: @SamIam I am trying to execute the files in the list one by one using CMD.Your Example Works fine by itself but as soon as i replace new text document with my string ,it doesn't work

Comment: @SamIam i finally got it to work.i used  " /c"+ fn in my argument to get it work.Thank you for all the help